# How to hide the "Save your changes" confirmation window when saving a page on Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I have a personal wiki running on mediawiki and don't think I really need to track the page edit summary or whatsoever, so is there anyway to skip it? which means when I am done with editing on a page and click on Save, it just Save it without asking me to describe what I changed..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this MediaWiki post](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:W3v5bj74bvev0pkh):

> Adding this at the beginning of ve.init.mw.ArticleTarget.prototype.showSaveDialog

```
this.save(this.getDocToSave(), this.getSaveOptions());
this.tryTeardown(true);
return;
```

> Seems to save the changes without annoying popup and leave the editing mode. But it still requires a manual page refresh (or clicking the Page tab) to see the saved changes.